# Cannot set guifont or guifontwide to installed font

Tags: gvim, font

OS and desktop environment info:

```
uname -a
Linux debian 5.10.0-18-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.140-1 (2022-09-02) x86_64 GNU/Linux
sudo dpkg -s lxde | grep Version
Version: 11
sudo dpkg -s lxappearance | grep Version
Version: 0.6.3-1+b1
```

The `增`, which mean enlarge in Chinese, is shown as below in OpenOffice with "Noto Sans CJK SC" :

[image: shown in openoffice]

I set `guifontwide` as `Noto\ Sans\ CJK\ SC\ 80` in my vimrc.

```
set guifont=Bitstream\ Vera\ Sans\ Mono\ 80
set guifontwide=Noto\ Sans\ CJK\ SC\ 14
```

Open a file containing `增` with vim:

```
echo  "增" > test.txt
vim test.txt
```

[image: shown in vim]

In vim, `set guifontwide?` shows the value "Noto Sans CJK SC 80", but compared to the image shown in OpenOffice with "Noto Sans CJK SC 80", these are different thing! A friend of me told that it is shown with the font called "VL Gothic,VL ゴシック" in vim.

How to tell vim to use "Noto Sans CJK SC" for wide characters instead of "VL Gothic,VL ゴシック"?

---

To check if the font-family name is something different, I tried `:set guifont=*`, which lets me select a font interactively.

There are so many fonts related to "Noto CJK SC":

```
fc-list | grep  Noto | grep CJK | grep SC
/usr/share/fonts/opentype/noto/NotoSerifCJK-Bold.ttc: Noto Serif CJK SC:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/opentype/noto/NotoSansCJK-Regular.ttc: Noto Sans CJK SC:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/opentype/noto/NotoSerifCJK-SemiBold.ttc: Noto Serif CJK SC,Noto Serif CJK SC SemiBold:style=SemiBold,Regular
/usr/share/fonts/opentype/noto/NotoSansCJK-Black.ttc: Noto Sans CJK SC,Noto Sans CJK SC Black:style=Black,Regular
/usr/share/fonts/opentype/noto/NotoSerifCJK-Regular.ttc: Noto Serif CJK SC:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/opentype/noto/NotoSansCJK-Light.ttc: Noto Sans CJK SC,Noto Sans CJK SC Light:style=Light,Regular
/usr/share/fonts/opentype/noto/NotoSerifCJK-ExtraLight.ttc: Noto Serif CJK SC,Noto Serif CJK SC ExtraLight:style=ExtraLight,Regular
/usr/share/fonts/opentype/noto/NotoSerifCJK-Light.ttc: Noto Serif CJK SC,Noto Serif CJK SC Light:style=Light,Regular
/usr/share/fonts/opentype/noto/NotoSansCJK-Thin.ttc: Noto Sans CJK SC,Noto Sans CJK SC Thin:style=Thin,Regular
/usr/share/fonts/opentype/noto/NotoSerifCJK-Black.ttc: Noto Serif CJK SC,Noto Serif CJK SC Black:style=Black,Regular
/usr/share/fonts/opentype/noto/NotoSerifCJK-Medium.ttc: Noto Serif CJK SC,Noto Serif CJK SC Medium:style=Medium,Regular
/usr/share/fonts/opentype/noto/NotoSansCJK-DemiLight.ttc: Noto Sans CJK SC,Noto Sans CJK SC DemiLight:style=DemiLight,Regular
/usr/share/fonts/opentype/noto/NotoSansCJK-Medium.ttc: Noto Sans CJK SC,Noto Sans CJK SC Medium:style=Medium,Regular
/usr/share/fonts/opentype/noto/NotoSansCJK-Bold.ttc: Noto Sans Mono CJK SC:style=Bold
/usr/share/fonts/opentype/noto/NotoSansCJK-Regular.ttc: Noto Sans Mono CJK SC:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/opentype/noto/NotoSansCJK-Bold.ttc: Noto Sans CJK SC:style=Bold
```

None of them can be selected by `set guifont=*`

[image]

Comment: I'm out of suggestion now. I don't know much about fonts. But I'm sure someone else can help now.

Comment: I edited your title because it seems like the main problem is that you cannot use your font at all in gvim: the problem with `guifontwide` is just one effect of this. Feel free to change it back or edit it further if you disagree.